# Keeping an apt-based distro, running as a web server, up to date

Tags: security, debian-based

I am in the process of configuring a production web server running Debian 5.0. How do you keep an apt-based distro up to date. Is there any best practice or magical ways of doing it? Logging in via ssh and running `apt-get upgrade` manually seems unrational.

**EDIT:**
After some discussion in the comments I am now deciding to upgrade the server manually but would like to know how to keep up to date with what packages to apply.

Comment: doing this automaticly could break your production server without any visible reason. upgrades on server machines should be handled by admins with some knowledge

Comment: Ok. I see your point. Another question arises though. How do you as an admin keep up to date with when patches for security vulnerabilities are available?

Comment: Well, im not a professional sys administrator so i would edit your question to reflect your comment, maybe tag it differently. You would probably need to be alert to your distributions update site, and update only the packages you feel wont possibly break your production system. Running some trials on your Quality or Integration systems would probably be best. this is my personal and non savvy opinion =D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Automatically updating your server *could* be problematic; the installation could fail, the new package could have slightly different behavior (debian is pretty good at avoiding this), or a condition might have changed which only becomes evident when package installation forces a service restart, etc. So I would advise against unattended package installs.

That being said, you could look into [cron-apt](http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-email-notification-upon-available-package-updates-with-cron-apt), which you can configure to do just that, or to download the packages in advance, and alert you about the available updates so that all you have to do is log in and install them.

Additionally/alternatively, you could subscribe to [debian-security-announce](http://lists.debian.org/debian-security-announce/), which sends out notices of new security updates.

Comment: would just like to add that any upgrade to a production server should have been tested under simmilar conditions on other ambient type machines